# rails teaspoon Testing in engine Not loading *_spec.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubygems, teaspoon

i'm working on an engine (gem) that has some js code to be tested but seems i can't get it working. I've followed the [wiki article](https://github.com/modeset/teaspoon/wiki/Testing-Engine-Assets) and set a basic example, but i'm only getting `0 examples, 0 failures`.

### Steps done:

- Added s.add_development_dependency 'teaspoon-jasmine' in the gemspec file
- dummy is in spec/dummy
- spec/teaspoon_env.rb:

  ```
  unless defined?(Rails)
    ENV["RAILS_ROOT"] = File.expand_path("../dummy", __FILE__)
    require File.expand_path("#{ENV["RAILS_ROOT"]}/config/environment", __FILE__)
  end

  Teaspoon.configure do |config|
     ...
     config.root = MyEngineName::Engine.root
     ...
  end
  ```
- Rakefile:

  ```
  desc "Run the javascript specs"
  task :teaspoon => "app:teaspoon"
  ```
- spec/javascripts/spec_helper.js (default as it was generated)
- spec/javascripts/example_spec.js:

  ```
  describe("My great feature", function() {
    it("Bang", () => {
      expect(true).toBe(false);
    });
  });
  ```

---

The problem is that when i try to run the test engine, i'm getting:

```
    $> teaspoon 
    Starting the Teaspoon server...
    Thin web server (v1.7.0 codename Dunder Mifflin)
    Maximum connections set to 1024
    Listening on 127.0.0.1:57036, CTRL+C to stop
    Teaspoon running default suite at http://127.0.0.1:57036/teaspoon/default


    Finished in 0.01600 seconds
    0 examples, 0 failures
```

I've also try to run the following commands, with the same result:

- $> bundle exec teaspoon
- $> rake teaspoon
- $> bundle exec teaspoon spec/javascripts/example_spec.js
- And even $> bundle exec teaspoon spec/javascripts/non_existent_file_spec.js

I have not much idea of what is not working. As non standard app, i'm using es6 through browserify-rails (which is working ok), and got in engine.rb:

```
    config.browserify_rails.paths = [
        lambda { |p| p.start_with?(MyEngineName::Engine.root.join("app").to_s) }
    ]
```

Any help or clue would be much appreciated.

## UPDATE:

I've created an engine from strach so it is easy to check and reproduce the issue.

[Repo Engine example](https://github.com/ngelx/engine_teaspoon_example)

In particular, the commit related to the teaspoon setup is [this one](https://github.com/ngelx/engine_teaspoon_example/commit/d3589cc059e1679e8f3972006f791e70b073dd8c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to the arrow function in your test. Change it to vanilla JS to make it work:

```
it("Bang", function() {
  expect(true).toBe(false);
});
```

The browser option works just fine with es6.

Comment: Thanks dude!! that was the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Rake command for the Rakefile

```
rake spec
```

Comment: It is not a Rspec, it is a Teaspoon!